# Can I use Day-Stout-Warren to rebalance a Binary Search Tree implemented in an array?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, tree

So, I've implemented a binary search tree backed by an array. The full implementation is [here](https://github.com/dishbreak/cracking-coding/blob/742a326ade4ff5d987be489a2b7956184bdb5599/src/com/dishbreak/testlab/tree/SearchTree.java).

Because the tree is backed by an array, I determine left and right children by performing arithmetic on the current index.

```
private Integer getLeftIdx(Integer rootIndex) {
    return 2 * rootIndex + 1;
}

private Integer getRightIdx(Integer rootIndex) {
    return 2 * rootIndex + 2;
}
```

I've realized that this can become really inefficient as the tree becomes unbalanced, partly because the array will be sparsely populated, and partly because the tree height will increase, causing searches to tend towards O(n).

I'm looking at ways to rebalance the tree, but I keep coming across algorithms like [Day-Stout-Warren](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Day%E2%80%93Stout%E2%80%93Warren_algorithm) which seem to rely on a linked-list implementation for the tree.

Is this just the tradeoff for an array implementation? I can't seem to think of a way to rebalance without creating a second array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine you have an array of length M that contains N items (with N < M, of course) at various positions, and you want to redistributed them into "valid positions" without changing their order.

To do that you can first walk through the array from end to start, packing all the items together at the end, and then walk through the array from start to end, moving an item into each valid position you find until you run out of items.

This easy problem is the *same as your problem*, except that you don't want to walk though the array in "index order", you want to walk through it in binary in-order traversal order.

You want to move all the items into "valid positions", i.e. the part of the array corresponding to indexes < N, and you don't want to change their in-order traversal order.

So, walk the array in reverse in-order order, packing items into the in-order-last-possible positions.  Then walk forward over the items in order, putting each item into the in-order-first available valid position valid position until you run out of items.

BUT NOTE:  This is fun to consider, but it's not going to make your tree efficient for inserts -- you have to do too many rebalancings to keep the array at a reasonable size.

BUT BUT NOTE:  You don't actually have to rebalance the whole tree.  When there's no free place for the insert, you only have to rebalance the smallest subtree on the path that has an extra space.  I vaguely remember a result that I think applies, which suggests that the amortized cost of an insert using this method is O(log^2 N) when your array has a fixed number of extra levels.  I'll do the math and figure out the real cost when I have time.

Comment: Nuanced but important point. Thanks! Would a self-balancing tree like red-black help with this?

Comment: @VishalKotcherlakota no.  A red-black tree is not balanced enough to make storage in an array efficient.  Also, the rebalancing operations that are fast (constant time) in a linked tree are very slow (linear time) in a tree array.

Answer (score 1):

> I keep coming across algorithms like Day-Stout-Warren which seem to rely on a linked-list implementation for the tree.

That is not quite correct. The [original paper](http://web.eecs.umich.edu/~qstout/pap/CACM86.pdf) discusses the case where the tree is embedded into an array. In fact, section 3 is devoted to the changes necessary. It shows how to do so with constant auxiliary space.

Note that there's a difference between their implementation and yours, though.

Your idea is to use a binary-heap order, where once you know a single-number index *i*, you can determine the indices of the children (or the parent). The array is, in general, not sorted in increasing indices.

The idea in the paper is to use an array sorted in increasing indices, and to compact the elements toward the beginning of the array on a rebalance. Using this implementation, you would not specify an element by an index *i*. Instead, as in binary search, you would indirectly specify an element by a pair *(b, e)*, where the idea is that the index is implicitly specified as *⌊(b + e) / 2⌋*, but the information allows you to determine how to go left or right.

Comment: Thanks for referencing the original paper--it's a good reminder that being a wikipedia scholar can only get you so far.